# C++ Parent class calling a child virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I want a pure virtual parent class to call a child implementation of a function like so:

```
class parent
{
  public:
    void Read() { //read stuff }
    virtual void Process() = 0;
    parent() 
    {
        Read();
        Process();
    }
}
class child : public parent
{
  public:
    virtual void Process() { //process stuff }
    child() : parent() { }
}

int main()
{
   child c;
}
```

This should work, but I get an unlinked error :/ This is using VC++ 2k3

Or shouldn't it work, am I wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Title of the following article says it all: [Never Call Virtual Functions during Construction or Destruction](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html).

Comment: Correct, but somewhat short. You should at least copied the conclusion: "Things to Remember: Don't call virtual functions during construction or destruction, because such calls will never go to a more derived class than that of the currently executing constructor or destructor."

Comment: Still, I really think you should think twice before mixing in functionality by inheritance.  IMHO, this question shows a design flow under the surface.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively,  make a factory method for creating the objects and make the constructors private,  the factory method can then Initialize the object after construction.

Answer (score 2):

Will work in general, but not for calls within the constructor of the pure virtual base class. At the time the base class in constructed, the sub-class override doesn't exist, so you can't call it. As long as you call it once the entire object is constructed, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your call is in the constructor. The derived class will not be valid until the constructor has completed so you compiler is right in dinging you for this.

There are two solutions:

1. Make the call to Process() in the derived class's constructor
2. define a blank function body for Process as in the following example:

```
class parent
{
  public:
    void Read() { //read stuff }
    virtual void Process() { }
    parent() 
    {
        Read();
        Process();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous, defining a blank function body in the parent and calling it in its constructor will result in only the parent part of Process() (i.e. nothing) being executed. He likely wants the call to be resolved as a virtual function, that's impossible in the constructor

Comment: Indeed: the blank function will be called.  That's no viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

With one step more you could just introduce some kind of a function like

```
class parent
{
    public:
        void initialize() {
            read();
            process();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The **superficial** problem is that you call a virtual function that's not known yet (Objects are constructed from Parent to Child, thus so are the vtables).  Your compiler warned you about that.

The **essential** problem, as far as I can see, is that you try to reuse functionality by inheritance.  This is almost always a bad idea.  A design issue, so to speak :)

Essentially, you try instantiating a Template Method pattern, to separate the *what* from the *when*: first read some data (in some way), then process it (in some way).

This will probably much better work with aggregation: give the Processing function to the Template method to be called at the right time.  Maybe you can even do the same for the Read functionality.

The aggregation can be done in two ways:

1. Using virtual functions (i.e. Runtime Binding)
2. Using templates (i.e. Compile Time Binding)

Example 1: runtime binding

```
class Data {};
class IReader    { public: virtual Data read()            = 0; };
class IProcessor { public: virtual void process( Data& d) = 0; };

class ReadNProcess {
public:
    ReadNProcess( IReader& reader, IProcessor processor ){
       processor.process( reader.read() );
    }
};
```

Example 2: compiletime binding

```
template< typename Reader, typename Writer > // definitely could use concepts here :)
class ReadNProcess {
public:
     ReadNProcess( Reader& r, Processor& p ) {
         p.process( r.read() );
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap in inside an object that calls the virtual method after the object is fully constructed:

```
class parent
{
  public:
    void Read() { /*read stuff*/ }
    virtual void Process() = 0;
    parent()
    {
        Read();
    }
};

class child: public parent
{
  public:
    virtual void Process() { /*process stuff*/ }
    child() : parent() { }
};

template<typename T>
class Processor
{
    public:
        Processor()
            :processorObj() // Pass on any args here
        {
            processorObj.Process();
        }
    private:
        T   processorObj;

};




int main()
{
   Processor<child> c;
}
```