# How to Invoke Child Function when Deriving from Parent with identical virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Lets say I have a parent Class:

```
Class Parent{
public:
virtual void doSomething(){}
}
```

and two children:

```
Class Son: public Parent{
public:
  void doSomething(){
  // Do one thing
  }
}

Class Daughter: public Parent{
public:
  void doSomething(){
  // Do another thing
  }
}
```

If I setup an instance of a child class like this:

```
Parent obj = Son();
```

How do I properly invoke the `doSomething()` method that is defined by `Son` and not the empty function in `Parent`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313622/calling-method-of-child-class-on-a-vector-of-parent-class

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818259/c-how-to-call-a-parent-class-method-from-contained-class

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847661/calling-a-child-class-method-when-processing-a-list-of-parent-class-objects

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568778/c-call-overwritten-child-function-within-parent-function

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754590/possible-for-a-parent-class-to-call-its-child-class-version-of-a-function

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232030/c-parent-class-calling-a-child-virtual-function

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580779/call-pure-virtual-function-from-parent-class

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498766/c-call-virtual-method-in-child-class

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the slicing problem in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to do this you need to make the `Parent` declaration a pointer or a reference.

```
Parent* obj = new Son();
```

In it's current form your declaring `obj` to be an instance of `Parent`.  This means the assignment from `Son()` doesn't create a reference to a `Son` instance, instead it slices the object into a `Parent` value.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

Comment: And what if I wanted to contain a list of objects in say an stl vector? Would that require a vector of pointers?

Comment: @slayton Yes. That's precisely right. Though you may want to look into unique_ptr or shared_ptr for easier memory management.